# What is a trampoline in this context?

Tags: javascript, promise

In the [Promises/A+ spec (section 3)](https://promisesaplus.com) it says:

> Since the promise implementation is considered platform code, it may
>   itself contain a task-scheduling queue or “trampoline” in which the
>   handlers are called.

What is a trampoline in this context?

Comment: [Wikipedia explains](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Trampoline_(computing)#/High-level_programming) that *a trampoline is a loop that iteratively invokes [thunk](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Thunk_(functional_programming))-returning functions ([continuation-passing style](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Continuation-passing_style))*.

Comment: Is the JavaScript event loop a trampoline? I suppose my question is: why mention in the Promise/A+ spec what appears to be an implementation detail? Is there a particular significance of a trampoline in this instance?

Comment: [This is an example for a trampoline](https://github.com/bergus/F-Promise/blob/master/src/continuations.js#L23-L27) in a very convoluted (and therefore abandoned) promise implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A trampoline is a control-structure that enables the implementation of recursive logic while avoiding the limitations of stack-based languages without tail-call optimization.

The recursive nature of nested promise chains lends itself to a recursive solution for a promise implementation.

Presumably the trampoline is therefore identified in the Promise/A+ specification as a commonly used implementation method even though it is not necessary or indeed might be sub-optimal in some languages.

For example ES2015 introduced tail-call optimisation into JavaScript, making a (user-land at least) trampoline, presumably no-longer necessary. The Promises/A+ spec was written years before ES2015 however.